# linking tables with third table

Tags: database, rdbms

Long time reader, first time poster.  I have 2 tables like so:

Div (ID, Amount,...)
Txn (ID, Amount,...)

Sometimes there is an association between the 2, where the Div table ID needs to be captured in the Txn table, but not always.  There will only ever be 1 Txn record associated with 1 Div record, if at all.  Also, when the Div record is deleted I'd like the corresponding Txn record to be deleted, if one exists.

My question is; should I just add a "DivID" field to the Txn table and manage the deletes through the application, or would it be better to add a third table with DivID and TxnID to capture the relationship?

Thanks for your thoughts.
Tim

Answer (score 1):

I would add DivId in Txn table, add it as foreign key, and when create (or alter) the table, set option On Delete Cascade . when query it, you can use Left Join since not every Div has a record in Txn. When delete, because you set the option, it will force to delete the record in Txn.